# How to identify customized images element present inside a table cell on Appium inspector for IOS 10.2 device?

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios

I am not able to identify Images inside a tableview cell using appium inspector, can anybody help me out why this is happening or how can I inspect image inside  table view cell in iOS platform.

Comment: Hi, In the app, enable the Table Cell accessibility  by code/details window, now you can access the image, statictext and ect.. inside cell